# How to manually render angular datatables?

Tags: angularjs, datatables

I am using [angular-datatables](https://github.com/l-lin/angular-datatables.git) with server side processing. When you specify the datatable attribute in table it will be transformed as datatable. But I want to manually do this after resolving one Ajax request.

```
$scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder
 .newOptions()
 .withOption('ajax', {
   url: config.apiBasePath + '/getTasks',
   type: 'GET',
   beforeSend: (xhr)->
    xhr.setRequestHeader('access-token', $scope.user.api_key)
    xhr.setRequestHeader('uid', $scope.user.uid)
  })
.withDataProp('data')
.withOption('processing', true)
.withOption('serverSide', true)
.withPaginationType('full_numbers')

$scope.dtColumns = [
 DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('title').withTitle('Title'),
 DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('keywords').withTitle('Keywords')
 DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('number_of_completions').withTitle('Number Of Completions')
 DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('reward_per_completion').withTitle('Reward Per Completion')
]
```

In the above code datatable ajax request should be initiated after $scope.user resolved. Else I am getting 401.

I don't see any doc to manually setup datatables. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ngIf` directive. The content will be processed only when the condition is met:

```
<div ng-if="user">
    <table datatable dt-options="dtOptions" dt-columns="dtColumns"></table>
</div>
```

In this example, if the user is not defined or null, then the condition is not met. Only when you assign `$scope.user` will the condition be met.